# Fastest way to add shapely geometries to a PostGis database using geoalchemy2

Tags: postgis, shapely, geoalchemy

I am looking for the absolute fastest approach to adding +10,000 shapely geometry objects to a  PostGIS database using geoalchemy2.

I'm having no speed issues when uploading to a localhost postgres server, but when I upload directly to my remote server it takes 35x as long!

I realize this might be a server question and not appropriate for this site, but curious if anyone has a successful workflow for:

**Quickly uploading shapely geometries to a PostGIS database using geoalchemy2**

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is your uplink to the remote server.

The "uplink" to your localhost postgresql server is the speed of your harddrive (~100MB/s for HDD and 500MB/s for SDD). Fast internet connections usually have up to 10Mbit/s, which is roughly 1MB/s. So one solution is to get a better connection with a higher uplink speed.

Another solution would be:

- Add data to localhost
- Dump the data using for example pg_dump with custom format
- compress the dump again (zip, rar, 7zip etc)
- upload the dump to your server
- restore the dump using pg_restore

Usually the dumps in custom format are much smaller than the original data, so its worth a try.